# How to generate qr code using data from firebase firestore flutter android?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i have this code that i got from the web to generate a qr code but can only recieve a string data. tried already to modify it and was able to displa the list but not ferom firestore.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myadnumobile/read%20data/get_user_data.dart';
import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class qrScanPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _qrScanPageState();
}

class _qrScanPageState extends State<qrScanPage> {
  
  String qrData =
      "test";
        // already generated qr code when the page opens

String _buildQrCode() { 
  var content = 's';
  var type;
  var email;
  var mac;
  Map<String,dynamic> myData = {
    'type': type,
    'content': content,
    'email': email,
    'mac': mac,
  };

  String encodedJson = jsonEncode(myData);
  print(encodedJson);
  return encodedJson;
}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
  final uid = user.uid;
    var endcodedJson = _buildQrCode();
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus(),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(31, 146, 144, 144),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('QR Code Generator'),
          actions: <Widget>[],
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(31, 146, 144, 144),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                QrImage(
                  //plce where the QR Image will be shown
                  data: endcodedJson,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  "New QR Link Generator",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.white),
                ),
                TextField(
                  controller: qrdataFeed,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),   
                          ),  
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                       ),  
                    hintText: "Input your data",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 20, 40, 0),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    child: Text('Generate QR',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                            ),
                    onPressed: _buildQrCode,
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                ),
                                primary: Colors.white,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 70, vertical: 12), //padding for the button
                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18,
                                  )
                            ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  final qrdataFeed = TextEditingController();
}
```

It can generate qr code but not a map from firestore. i expect  it to display the fields and keys from firestore database of the current user

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

[Skany QR Code Reader and Generator](https://github.com/manishgautammg3994/skany/tree/advanced)

```
visit Above link
```

licenced

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).